# Remove shadow from image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to remove the shadow of the pipe in the following image.

[image: Original Pipe]

I use the following code to isolate the pipe with the shadow but I cannot find a way to remove the shadow.

```
img = cv2.imread("myimage.png",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

img_X = img.shape[1] / 2
img_Y = img.shape[0]
img_cnts = None
img_distance = None

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 500:
        continue

    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cnt_X = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cnt_Y = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    cnt_distance = math.sqrt(sum((px - qx) ** 2.0 for px, qx in zip([cnt_X, cnt_Y], [img_X, img_Y])))
        
    if img_distance == None or img_distance > cnt_distance:
        img_cnts = c
        img_distance = cnt_distance

mask = np.zeros_like(img) # Create mask where white is what we want, black otherwise
cv2.drawContours(mask, [img_cnts], -1, (255,255,255), -1) # Draw filled contour in mask
out = np.zeros_like(img) # Extract out the object and place into output image
out[mask == 255] = img[mask == 255]
```

This is the result of the previous code that is pretty close to what I need.

[image: Isolated Pipe]

I tried to use cv2.adaptiveThreshold and cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you apply `adaptive-threshold` along with `bitwise-not` operation result will be:

[image]

Of course, different `blockSize` and `C` parameters you will get different results.

Where:  ([source](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html))

`blockSize`: determines the size of the neighbourhood area

`C`: constant that is subtracted from the mean or weighted sum of the neighbourhood pixels.

Code:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("pdUqL.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, blockSize=33, C=31)
bnt = cv2.bitwise_not(thr)
cv2.imshow("out", bnt)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no good way to remove the shadow. you need to fix your lighting. use "softboxes" (indirect lighting), multiple lights from multiple angles, and whenever you have mirror surfaces, arrange lights so they don't reflect off that into the camera.